# SQL Server - Add text at the beginning of each record

Tags: sql-server

I need to add the same string to the beginning of each record for a varchar column. How would I go about doing this?

So the contents in that column currently look like this:

```
| TableNames |
--------------
| Table1     |
| Table2     |
| Table3     |
| Table4     |
```

And I want them to be:

```
| TableNames |
--------------
| dbo.Table1 |
| dbo.Table2 |
| dbo.Table3 |
| dbo.Table4 |
```

Comment: `update T set TableNames  = 'dbo.' + TableNames`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You get your table names from `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`. There you'll find the table's name and schema...

Comment: It smells like somebody is venturing down the over zealous dynamic sql path.

Comment: @Shnugo something work related. We have a table that contains database and table names and other relevant information about the table.

Comment: @AlexK. thanks that worked. I thought that would be the correct way, but I didn't want to execute it without know what it would do and lose the original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update the table by using its own entry (TableNames column) like this:

```
update MyTable set TableNames = 'dbo.' + TableNames;
commit;
```

and commit is just to commit the execution result.